# Laravel - Why on localhost only home page route working on my project

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, routes

I run my laravel project on localhost/sm folder. Here is the screenshoot of my folder. In project folder i keep the files and I keep the public folder component in root sm folder. But when I try to run the project only homepage work. but for other pages in every time I have to put /sm follow the route manually.
So, how to take over this problem. Here is my htacees file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

[image: File structure]

Comment: "I have to put /sm follow the route manually" - What do you mean by this? What URL are you requesting? Requests for the home page is not dependent on mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` to call your front-controller. Have you confirmed that mod_rewrite and `.htaccess` overrides are enabled on your server?

Comment: don't you need blade files when working with Laravel? and they should be in resources folder

Comment: That is because your laravel exists in a subfolder and the routing does not expect the /sm in the url. Why are you running Laravel on XAMPP? thats not the best option for Laravel development?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue, and after a lot of search i found that the problem was in relation with the request sent from my postman client.
I had just to mention `Accept: application/json` in headers.
just in case someone faced the same issue in the future.